# Is there a pythonic way to concatenate groups of columns from a matrix along the first axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm working with a m x n numpy 2D-array which holds some integer values. The dimensions are unknown before executing the script, but n (the width) is always even. Something like:

```
[[  1   2   3   4]
 [  1   2   3   4]
 [  1   2   3   4]
 [  1   2   3   4]
 [  1   2   3   4]]
```

What I need is to group the columns in pairs and concatenate them along the first axis:

```
[[  1   2]
 [  1   2]
 [  1   2]
 [  1   2]
 [  1   2]
 [  3   4]
 [  3   4]
 [  3   4]
 [  3   4]
 [  3   4]]
```

I tried using `reshape` but that doesn't output the expected result. I'm not very used to program in Python and would be able to implement it using loops and if statements, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: What would you consider pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose the matrix between the `reshape`:

```
# sample
a = np.stack([[1,2,3,4, 5, 6]]*2)

a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1, 2).transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that it is not necessary to compute the 1 axis length

Answer (score 1):

hi with reshape you can choose to start with the columns like this:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
a.reshape((8,2),order='F')
```

Comment: So far it is giving my the correct output, I also tested it with a "-1" in the first dimension. What could be the difference you are talking about @QuangHoang ?

Comment: @Nedo it gives me `[[1,3],[1,3]...` instead of `[[1,2],[1,2],...` as in your expected output.

Comment: @QuangHoang, you are right! I was testing it on a m x 4 "symmetric" array and thus was not noticing the error.